# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Tags: sqoop, hadoop2

```
15/10/12 11:46:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/pc83/.staging/job_1444630501195_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:65)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:36)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
pc83@pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p:~$
```

When i'm goint to run the following command i got issue like below

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SQOOP_TABLES --username root --password root123 --table salaries -m 1
```

I have created SQOOP_TABLES in mysql along with table salaries comprised of four fields.

so, please help me to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I solved it.
My sqoop version was not compatible with the hadoop version.

I configured the sqoop again by following the steps-6 to 8 of the below link.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqoop/sqoop_installation.htm

> ### Step 6: Configuring Sqoop
>
> To configure Sqoop with Hadoop, you need to edit the `sqoop-env.sh`
>   file, which is placed in the `$SQOOP_HOME/conf` directory. First of all,
>   Redirect to Sqoop config directory and copy the template file using
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> $ cd $SQOOP_HOME/conf $ mv sqoop-env-template.sh sqoop-env.sh
> ```
>
> Open `sqoop-env.sh` and edit the following lines:
>
> ```
> export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop  export
> HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
> ```
>
> ### Step 7: Download and Configure `mysql-connector-java`
>
> We can download `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.tar.gz` file from the
>   following [link](http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/MySQL/Downloads/Connector-J/).
>
> The following commands are used to extract `mysql-connector-java`
>   tarball and move `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar` to
>   `/usr/lib/sqoop/lib` directory.
>
> ```
> $ tar -zxf mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.tar.gz $ su password:
>
> # cd mysql-connector-java-5.1.30
> # mv mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib
> ```
>
> ### Step 8: Verifying Sqoop
>
> The following command is used to verify the Sqoop version.
>
> ```
> $ cd $SQOOP_HOME/bin $ sqoop-version
> ```
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> 14/12/17 14:52:32 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5 Sqoop
> 1.4.5 git commit id 5b34accaca7de251fc91161733f906af2eddbe83 Compiled by abe on Fri Aug 1 11:19:26 PDT 2014
> ```
>
> Sqoop installation is complete.